# how to open excel file with microsoft excel in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am using the below code for the purpose . i am using using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel; i know it is not recommended to use on server but somehow i want this functionality and interop seems to be easy to use

```
string myServerPath = Server.MapPath("Tool.xlsx.xlsm");
Application excel = new Application();
excel.Visible = true;
Workbook wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(myServerPath);
Worksheet sh = wb.Sheets[1];
```

this code works perfectly on my local machine but not on the server ... can i get this to work on server or any other way to server the purpose

Comment: In what way does it not work on the server? Please describe the problem you are having, and what you have tried to resolve it. Are you getting errors?

Comment: [Interop is not recommended](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office) because it's *not* easy to use. You will have difficult issues crop up. You're far better off using a library that manipulates the files directly such as EPPlus, NPOI, or Office XML SDK.

Answer (score -1):

Totally irrelevant and not to take away anything from what you did so far, if you are concerned about getting an office account for your server access, you can always use other libraries such as OpenXml and ClosedXml. You don't have to use any office accounts to work with spreadsheets.